# Rendering Interactive Table in Pyramid Framework

Tags: python, pandas, jinja2, pyramid

I'm trying to build a web page which searches through a text files based on what the user searches, and outputs the results from the text file in a table. I'm using Pyramid and Jinja2 templating for this.

My current approach is the following:

1. Take user input from a search bar
2. Initialize a Pandas dataframe
3. Fill dataframe based on user search by iterating through text file
4. Somehow render this dataframe in Pyramid

I'm currently stuck in step 4. My main goal is to be able to render this dataframe in the form of an interactive table, one which can sort the columns by clicking the column header (and perhaps one that allows the user to search through the table results as well, but not necessary).

Pandas does seem to have a to_html() method, but this only seems to return a static table.

What I'm look for is something like this: https://www.dynatable.com/

Ultimately, my questions are the following:

1. Does my approach make sense (using Pandas dataframe to represent table) for what I'm trying to accomplish or should I use another class to represent the data that I want to display?
2. Is there a library available that works well with Pyramid and will allow me to create an interactive table?

Comment: What's in your text file? You probably could generate a JSON data structure from the text file using plain old Python (a list of dictionaries, converted to JSON with `json_dumps`), which in turn can be consumed by Dynatable.js.

Comment: My text file is a few million lines of debug information that I'm parsing. It's definitely something I can spit out as JSON and use with Dynatable.js. If I go that route, how do I use jQuery and Dynatable with Pyramid?

Comment: I suggest you start with an example to learn from and forego your data for now. Take the example from Dynatable, create a Pyramid app from a cookiecutter, then customize the template with the example from Dynatable. Once you get that concept down, then you can figure out how to manipulate your data to send it into your template. If that doesn't help get you started, then try the [Quick Tutorial](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Looks like good places to start. I'll take a look at those examples and build from there. Thanks for the help!